# How to filter and sum data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that contains all the jobs, each job has an associated number of hours broken down by month in another table, it can have multiple hours over multiple years. Is there a way to filter based on the job and then sum the hours to display only the hours for each job?

Would something like this work?

```
<% total_hours = l.month_hours.pluck('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7','m8','m9','m10','m11','m12') %>
```

Comment: can you show your relations better?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your relations but if:

```
Job has_many Month
```

and

```
Month has a hours value
```

Then you could query the job and get all the hours like this:

```
hours = Job.find(id).months.map(&:hours).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: You should probably use [`.pluck(:hours)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) instead of `.map(&:hours)`.  However, it may be more fruitful to do `Job.find(id).months.sum(:hours)`, depending on types.

Comment: Relations are Job, has many hours years, in hours years, it is split by month. Also I am already going through a loop with the associated jobs in the second cell.